# How to Restart cmd every 30 Minutes with Node

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a bot and I want, this bot restart every 30minutes I have a .batch code to start the bot. Now I want this bot starts every 30min.

I have this :

node bot.js
pause

Comment: You would want to use an external scheduling tool to trigger the batch file. check these links and pick a tool: [wiki list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software), [freeware](http://listoffreeware.com/list-of-best-free-task-scheduler-software-for-windows/)

Comment: You can use process manager or else as @pkm mentioned you can use the external scheduling tools. If not then try out `pm2 manager` with `--restart-delay` option.

Answer (score 0):

old school (and not really good) solution is:

```
:label1
taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cmd.exe - MyBotName.bat"
start MyBotName.bat
ping -n 1801 127.0.0.1>nul
goto :label1
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work :/ my script dont stop it is always running

Comment: use `taskkill /f /im ProcessName.exe` to stop process first. if your process launched in cmd window, use taskkill /f /fi ""windowtitle eq %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cmd.exe - MyBotName" (answer updated)